# Good Resources for Voice Actors?

Tags: audio-drama, voice, actors

I'm about to embark on a new venture of producing short (for now) audio dramas, in the line of ZBS stuff. I use that comparison loosely and with nothing but utmost respect and adoration. I could begin to aspire to that level of work, but it's my main inspiration and the vibe I'm going for.

So anyway, I am looking for voice talent. I've found some sites online, some decent, others more like promotional meat markets. Anyone here have any experience with scouting voice actors and have recommendations on good places to look?

Comment: Someone posted a great answer below about theatre actors. Where did it go? 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what country you're in and how much of a budget you have but a good voice actor is hard to find yet can make your production a 100 times better. I recommend not cutting corners and using friends and family.

I'm in London and our company use SVMK http://www.svmk.co.uk/ and RED24 http://www.red24management.com/

Majority voice for radio and tv.

Goodluck

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the US, New York City to be exact. I'm sure there is an abundance of talent here, just want to avoid resorting to opening the Craigslist floodgates.

Answer (score 0):

Pro talent agencies or full-on interviewin/auditioning people in person are, IMO, the best ways to get solid talent with positive outlooks and solid work ethics. I've worked with STARS Agency here in SF, and had great success: All supremely professional, and a good talent base (i.e., voice styles to choose from). Not sure how far they extend in terms of geographical reach.

Knowing, networking, and hanging with actors, as Utopia said, also can land you with your own killer network of vocal talents that you can push a bit farther and rely upon more readily.